# Calculate percentages across rows using dplyr/plyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe x, like this.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(id = letters[1:3], c1 =runif(3,max=3), c2 = runif(3,max=2), c3 = runif(3,max=4))

# id        c1        c2        c3
# 1  a 0.3271498 1.8415800 0.3496333
# 2  b 1.4744138 1.3157962 1.9983840
# 3  c 2.6475328 0.8444028 3.9316721
```

I want to be able to calculate percentages across each individual row using dplyr, or another tidyverse package. Any ideas?

For instance, the output of x would be:

```
# id        c1        c2        c3
# 1  a 0.1299057 0.7312607 0.1388336
# 2  b 0.3079012 0.2747772 0.4173217
# 3  c 0.356637 0.1137456 0.5296174
```

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: or `cbind(x[, 1], prop.table(as.matrix(x[-1]), 1))`

Answer (score 3):

While not the most succinct, you can do this with `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

```
set.seed(10)
x <- data.frame(id = letters[1:3], c1 =runif(3,max=3), c2 = runif(3,max=2), c3 = runif(3,max=4))

x %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = value/sum(value)) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  spread(variable, percentage)

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: id [3]

      id        c1         c2         c3
* <fctr>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1      a 0.4329613 0.16112458 0.40591407
2      b 0.4502457 0.25160471 0.29814957
3      c 0.9019967 0.08077433 0.01722901
```